# Grails and Javascript

Tags: javascript, grails, dom-events

I would like to know how to use [tinybox](http://www.scriptiny.com/2009/05/javascript-popup-box/) in my Grails app.
I've tried this so far (placed it inside the head tags):

```
<g:javascript library="TinyBox/tinybox"/>   

<g:javascript>

    function errorResponse(){
        var b = ["Oh com'on!Say it!",
                "At least say a word!",
                "Don't be mean, say something. :)",
                "I'll be sa sad."];
        var a = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);            
        //alert(b[a]);
        TINY.box.show(b[a],0,0,0,0,3);
    }
</g:javascript>
```

And I called it somewhere inside my form:

```
...
<g:submitToRemote update="comments" url="[controller:'sushiTrail',action:'save']" value="Send" onFailure="errorResponse();" onSuccess=" comment.value='';"></g:submitToRemote>
...
```

I'm new to both grails and Javascript. Tinybox is supposed to load when validation fails. I've tried a simple `alert()` and it worked, and I seriously think there is something wrong with the way I call stuff. I followed the tinybox demo [here](http://sandbox.scriptiny.com/tinybox/), but I still can't get it going even though view source seems to be correct. Can someone enlighten me?

Note: there was no error. The tinybox just didn't appear. :(

Answer (score 1):

The `<g:javascript>` [tag](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/javascript.html) only accepts values "prototype", "scriptaculous", "yahoo" or "dojo" for the library attribute, so the following won't work:

```
<g:javascript library="TinyBox/tinybox"/>
```

Add the tinybox JavaScript files to the Grails application's `web-app/js` directory and use one of the following instead to import it:

```
<g:javascript src="path/to/tinybox.js" />
```

or

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="path/to/tinybox.js"></script>
```